# Boost::geometry::intersection with C++

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

I'm a PhD student in civil engineering and I recently started doing some coding in C++, basically I'm interested in getting the overlapping or intersection area of two polygons, which represent the projection of two soil particles.

I did a lot of search and I found that boost geometry is the best solution for me. I also did a lot of search for the specific problem I'm facing but I wasn't able to resolve my issue.

Here is the problem, the software I'm using is called PFC3D (particle flow code). I have to use microsoft visual studio 2010 to interact with this software and compile DLL files to run it in PFC.

My code work very well without the overlapping area. Here is the code:

```
// Includes for overlapping
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/core/point_type.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>enter code here
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> > polygon;
polygon poly1, poly2;
poly1 {{0.0,  0.0}, {0.0, 1.0}, {1.0, 1.0}, {1.0,  0.0}, {0.05,  0.0}};
poly2 {{0.5, -0.5}, {0.5, 0.5}, {1.5, 0.5}, {1.5, -0.5},  {0.5, -0.5}};
std::deque<polygon> output;
boost::geometry::intersection(poly1, poly2, output);
double area = boost::geometry::area(output);
```

The error I'm getting is in assigning the poly1 and poly2 coordinates. 
Hope you can help in this. Thanks!

Comment: What version of boost are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm using boost_1_65_0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well. `identifier { }` only ever works if `identifier` is a typename.

If you wanted uniform initialization, you use `{ }` to commence the constructor parameter list, and wrap each parameter ring in an extra set of `{ }`:

```
polygon poly1 { { { 0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 0.0 }, { 0.05, 0.0 } }  };
polygon poly2 { { { 0.5, -0.5 }, { 0.5, 0.5 }, { 1.5, 0.5 }, { 1.5, -0.5 }, { 0.5, -0.5 } }  };
```

Next, `area` doesn't expect a multi-polygon, so write a loop:

```
double area = 0;
for (auto& p : output)
    area += boost::geometry::area(p);
```

May I suggest looking at `dsv` parsing for the input:

```
polygon poly1, poly2;
bg::read<bg::format_wkt>(poly1, "POLYGON((0 0,0 1,1 1,1 0,0.05 0,0 0))");
bg::read<bg::format_wkt>(poly2, "POLYGON((0.5 -0.5,0.5 0.5,1.5 0.5,1.5 -0.5,0.5 -0.5))");
```

Live demo: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f795ef9e26cde1bb)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/io/io.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/algorithms/area.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;
namespace bgm = bg::model;
typedef bgm::polygon<bgm::d2::point_xy<double> > polygon;

int main() {
    polygon poly1, poly2;
    bg::read<bg::format_wkt>(poly1, "POLYGON((0 0,0 1,1 1,1 0,0.05 0,0 0))");
    bg::read<bg::format_wkt>(poly2, "POLYGON((0.5 -0.5,0.5 0.5,1.5 0.5,1.5 -0.5,0.5 -0.5))");

    std::cout << bg::wkt(poly1) << "\n";
    std::cout << bg::wkt(poly2) << "\n";
    std::deque<polygon> output;
    bg::intersection(poly1, poly2, output);


    double area = 0;
    for (auto& p : output)
        area += bg::area(p);
}
```

Comment: Sehe ... Thank you for these great info.
In defining the polygon's points, for example:  bg::read<bg::format_wkt>(poly1, "POLYGON((0 0,0 1,1 1,1 0,0.05 0,0 0))") ...... it looks to me that the inputs of the polygon vertices are strings which means that we can't update them. My code requires updating each polygon vertices each cycle. I mean that I need to initialize the polygon as points that can be modified . ..... I tried to use the first approach, polygon poly1 { { { 0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 0.0 }, { 0.05, 0.0 } }  }, but it also did not work

Comment: Of course the [first approach works](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qLHtMwmzN0SaUfwT). Are you using a C++11 compiler? By the way, the need for "updating the points" was ***exactly*** why I suggest reading them from somewhere. I mean, in your code you have to recompile to "update a point".

Comment: Oh hey, Coliru stopped being too slow to compile: [same](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1aec905ca7afef16)

Comment: I'm using Microsoft visual studio 2010 to compile my codes. I'm not sure if the 2010 version supports C++11 compiler

Comment: Oh well. I took the train back in time to make you this: http://rextester.com/ENSD31608. By the way, all the more reason to get your input from something else than code.

Comment: You are amazing, now the codes works properly ... thank you very very much ... So the problem was in the version of visual studio I have ... Thanks again for your time!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153972/discussion-between-k-jaradat-and-sehe).

Answer (score 0):

points in the polygon should be sorted by clockwise. such as

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/io/io.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/algorithms/area.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;
namespace bgm = bg::model;
typedef bgm::d2::point_xy<double> point;
typedef bgm::polygon<point> polygon;

void testOverlap_anticlockwise();
void testOverlap_clockwise();


int main() {
    testOverlap_anticlockwise();
    testOverlap_clockwise();
}



void testOverlap_anticlockwise()
{
    polygon poly1;
    poly1.outer().push_back(point(15, 0.176766));
    poly1.outer().push_back(point(0.176767, 15));
    poly1.outer().push_back(point(-5, 16.6844));
    poly1.outer().push_back(point(-5, -5));
    poly1.outer().push_back(point(16.6844, -5));
    poly1.outer().push_back(point(15, 0.176766));

    polygon poly2;
    poly2.outer().push_back(point(15, 15));
    poly2.outer().push_back(point(0, 15));
    poly2.outer().push_back(point(0, 0));
    poly2.outer().push_back(point(15, 0));
    poly2.outer().push_back(point(15, 15));

    std::cout << bg::wkt(poly1) << "\n";
    std::cout << bg::wkt(poly2) << "\n";
    std::deque<polygon> output;
    bg::intersection(poly1, poly2, output);

    double area = 0;
    for (std::deque<polygon>::const_iterator it = output.begin(); it != output.end(); ++it) {
        area += bg::area(*it);
    }
    std::cout << area << std::endl;
}

void testOverlap_clockwise()
{
    polygon poly1;
    poly1.outer().push_back(point(15, 0.176766));
    poly1.outer().push_back(point(0.176767, 15));
    poly1.outer().push_back(point(-5, 16.6844));
    poly1.outer().push_back(point(-5, -5));
    poly1.outer().push_back(point(16.6844, -5));
    poly1.outer().push_back(point(15, 0.176766));
    std::reverse(poly1.outer().begin(), poly1.outer().end());

    polygon poly2;
    poly2.outer().push_back(point(15, 15));
    poly2.outer().push_back(point(0, 15));
    poly2.outer().push_back(point(0, 0));
    poly2.outer().push_back(point(15, 0));
    poly2.outer().push_back(point(15, 15));
    std::reverse(poly2.outer().begin(), poly2.outer().end());

    std::cout << bg::wkt(poly1) << "\n";
    std::cout << bg::wkt(poly2) << "\n";
    std::deque<polygon> output;
    bg::intersection(poly1, poly2, output);

    double area = 0;
    for (std::deque<polygon>::const_iterator it = output.begin(); it != output.end(); ++it) {
        area += bg::area(*it);
    }
    std::cout << area << std::endl;
}
```

result is
POLYGON((15 0.176766,0.176767 15,-5 16.6844,-5 -5,16.6844 -5,15 0.176766))
POLYGON((15 15,0 15,0 0,15 0,15 15))
0

POLYGON((15 0.176766,16.6844 -5,-5 -5,-5 16.6844,0.176767 15,15 0.176766))
POLYGON((15 15,15 0,0 0,0 15,15 15))
115.136

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).